# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController hide cancel button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm subclassing `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and I was wondering how to hide the right toolbar item "`Cancel`"?

I've been searching but I couldn't find the right solution.

Thanks!

Comment: why you want to hide it..?

Comment: Have you tried `peoplePicker.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`?

Comment: @jjv360 Thanks, but it doesn't work, the rightBarButtonItem is still visible

Comment: Have you tried `rightBarButtonItem` instead then?

Comment: I tried both, same result, the UIBarButtonItems are still there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>`

After `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc` delegate it to self.

```
peoplePicker.delegate = self;
```

We will need to override an `UINavigationController`'s delegate method.

> // Called when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class]])
        navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Comment: Another question if I may, I have to implement numberOfRowsInSection, how can I returns the number of rows for each section ?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` for `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes, I access the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's tableView and set it's dataSource to self, but I need to implement numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: switch (section) {
        case 0:
             return 4;
}

Comment: Works fine for me thanks, but the cancel button reappears after using the searchbar. To fix this I implemented the `UISearchDisplayDelegate` and in the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method I set `viewController.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;`